# In Visual Studio 2019 how to ensure tab stays open after Go-To-Definition

Tags: visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio, if I Go-To-Definition on e.g. a class by <kbd>Ctrl+Click</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>, the class is opened in a new tab but the tab is not part of the open tabs (not sure if that is the correct wording). The tab heading is to the right. The tab heading has a little button "Keep Tab Open Ctrl+Alt+Home".

If I make no edits in the opened tab and navigate back using Ctrl-Minus, the new tab is closed.

What do I need to do to always have Go-To-Definition windows open and never close e.g. when navigate away?

Here some pictures @hellip;

This is the start situation:

[image: start]

This is the actual situation after <kbd>Ctrl+Click</kbd> on Class1:

[image: actual]

This is what I expect:

[image: expected]

Answer (score 6):

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Tabs And Windows
Uncheck "Allow new files to be opened in the preview tab"

You may need to restart Visual Studio for the setting to take effect.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019 with multiple solution windows open, I had to close them all down and restart for this setting to take effect.